# SAGE returning wrong minimal polynomial?

Tags: sage

```
sage: A

[    t     1     1     0 t + 1     1]
[    t     t     0 t + 1     t     1]
[    0     1 t + 1     0     t     0]
[    t     t     0     0     0     0]
[    0     1     0     1     1     1]
[    t     1     t     t     t     1]
sage: A.base_ring()
Finite Field in t of size 2^2
sage: A.minpoly()
x^5 + (t + 1)*x^4 + t*x^3
sage: A.minpoly()(A)

[1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

The result of the last command should have been the zero matrix, of course. I have no idea why it failed. So the question is what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this on OS X 10.6.8:

```
sage: version()
'Sage Version 4.8, Release Date: 2012-01-20'
sage: R.<t> = GF(4)
sage: R
Finite Field in t of size 2^2
sage: A = Matrix(R, [[t, 1, 1, 0, t+1, 1], [t,t,0,t+1,t,1,],[0,1,t+1,0,t,0],[t,t,0,0,0,0,],[0,1,0,1,1,1,],[t,1,t,t,t,1]])
sage: A
[    t     1     1     0 t + 1     1]
[    t     t     0 t + 1     t     1]
[    0     1 t + 1     0     t     0]
[    t     t     0     0     0     0]
[    0     1     0     1     1     1]
[    t     1     t     t     t     1]
sage: s = """
....: [    t     1     1     0 t + 1     1]
....: [    t     t     0 t + 1     t     1]
....: [    0     1 t + 1     0     t     0]
....: [    t     t     0     0     0     0]
....: [    0     1     0     1     1     1]
....: [    t     1     t     t     t     1]"""
sage: 
sage: str(A) == s.strip()
True
sage: A.minpoly()
x^6 + (t + 1)*x^5 + t*x^4
sage: A.minpoly()(A)
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Note the extra factor of x.  You didn't post your version number or any information about your architecture, so I don't know if it's an architecture-dependent linear algebra bug which is still present or one which has been fixed.  Sage 5.0 will be coming out relatively soon (it's currently at beta12) and upgrading is highly recommended.

Two meta-notes: Please post code that can be copied and pasted to reproduce the problem.  Also, you can always test your snippet on sagenb.org (or even test.sagenb.org) to see if your problem is still present in mainline and beyond.  Both seem to give the right answer.